# Find crossing point of polyline layer

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcobjects, .net

I have a polyline layer. I want to split this polyline layer at CROSSING POINT.
With two steps I want to do this.

1. I show the user the CROSSING POINT of polyline layer.
2. With this CROSSING POINT, I want to split the polyline layer.

I am on Arcgis 10 with .NET/arcpy. 
Second step can be done with  SPLIT LINE AT POINT tool. But how can I identify the crossing point?

I have attached image to clear my problem.

[image]

Comment: Can you add an image which enables some details to be seen, please?

Comment: Start editing, select all the features and use 'planarize' from the advanced edit toolbar... http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//01m800000012000000 (note: can be called from ArcObjects by component ID)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think I know what you mean, you should do that by 2 tools step by step first step find in arctoolbox intersect (Analysis) and then create intersect point layer in Intersection tools window choose "point" in output type field [intersect(Analysis)](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/how-intersect-analysis-works.htm)

finally [Step2] by [Split line at point](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/editing-fundamentals/ways-to-split-a-line-feature.htm) tools in ArcToolbox you can split polyline based on intersection points

for example:
Config your Intersection Tool window like below picture
[image]
Config your Split Line At Point like below picture
[image]

Comment: If you're doing this in ArcObjects you want to use an ISpatialFilter to find the intersecting features, combine into a multipart geometry then use ITopologicalOperator.Intersect http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//002m000003vs000000 with esriGeometry0Dimension to generate the multipoint where intersections occur between the lines. This question is tagged as 'ArcObjects' but I can't see any code so I'm thinking that tag might be erroneous, in which case I support this answer.

Comment: @Predator X, thanks for for your quick reply. It was helpful for me. But may be I have faced another problem. I have only one polyline feature in one polyline feature class. And this polyline feature has crossed itself. Then how can I find this crossing point?? INTERSECT tool may not gives self crossing point . Thanks again for your ans.

Comment: @Monir, your welcome, please pay attention to my sample, I used only one polyline feature class no more, it doesn't matter how many lines are in polyline feature class one or more than one, If line has cross even with itself, It's ok you can do it, try again.

Answer (score 2):

Although there is already an accepted answer to this question, as it was tagged as arcpy, I'd like to add one open source alternative by using one equivalent tool: PyQGIS.

My polyline layer was very similar to above question:

[image]

Complete code is:

```
import itertools

layer = iface.activeLayer()

feats = [ feat for feat in layer.getFeatures() ]

n = len(feats)

list = range(n)

points = [ feats[i].geometry().intersection(feats[j].geometry()).asPoint()
           for i,j in itertools.combinations(list, 2)
           if feats[i].geometry().intersects(feats[j].geometry()) ]

lines = [ [ points[i], points[j] ] 
            for i,j in itertools.combinations(list, 2) ]

epsg = layer.crs().postgisSrid()

uri = "Point?crs=epsg:" + str(epsg) + "&field=id:integer""&index=yes"

mem_layer = QgsVectorLayer(uri,
                           'points',
                           'memory')

prov = mem_layer.dataProvider()

feats = [ QgsFeature() for i in range(len(points)) ]

for i, feat in enumerate(feats):
    feat.setAttributes([i])
    feat.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPoint(points[i]))

prov.addFeatures(feats)

QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(mem_layer)

uri = "LineString?crs=epsg:" + str(epsg) + "&field=id:integer""&index=yes"

mem_layer = QgsVectorLayer(uri,
                           'lines',
                           'memory')

prov = mem_layer.dataProvider()

feats = [ QgsFeature() for i in range(len(lines)) ]

for i, feat in enumerate(feats):
    feat.setAttributes([i])
    feat.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPolyline(lines[i]))

prov.addFeatures(feats)

QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(mem_layer)
```

After running it at the Python Console of QGIS, I got crossing points and split polyline layer:

[image]